# I tried two way data binding (@output and @Input), this works best fro cross component. But did not work for cross module. Any suggestions???

Tags: html, angular

I am working on Angular 4 application. Architecture has several modules and I have to establish communication between different modules to send/receive data from different modules. I would like to know What is best to do this? I tried two way data binding (@output and @Input), this works best fro cross component. But did not work for cross module. Any suggestions???

Comment: Can you show your working code? Usually, the easiest way to communicate multiple components is to use services

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/ngrx/store , it's efficiency for communication between components.

Comment: Communication between different components is working for me but communication between different modules is not working

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution... :)
We need to use Subject object as an observable. This observable should be subscribed by component.ts. so whenever there is a change in property; html data gets updated.
Example:

In Example.service

```
   private exampleData= new Subject<any>();
   example$ = this.exampleData.asObservable();

   setExampleData(value){
   this.exampleData.next(value);
   }
```

In Example.Component

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this._exampleService.example$.subscribe(data => this.exampleData= data);
```

Now call setExampleData() wherever(from any other module) you want to update this.exampleData